# Redirect row to another row mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, redirect

```
id  name  redirect_id
1    ....    NULL
2   .....    NULL
3   .....    2
4    ....    NULL
5    ....    1
```

i have this table. `id` is `primary key`. I want to get `name` of the row. However if it has a `redirect_id`, i want to get redirected id's `name`. Is there a possible way to do it in one sql query?

I know how to do it after fetching the result array. However it becomes so tangled if i do it that way. 1 sql query would be so good here. Thanks.

**edit** i need all redirected row not just redirrected `name`.

Comment: Can there be more than one hop?

Comment: @GordonLinoff nope. just one redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ln.id
, COALESCE(ln2.name, ln.name)
from linkednames ln
left join linkednames ln2 on ln2.id = ln.redirect_id
```

Comment: hey thanks but i need all redirected row not just its name.  Should i make `select COALESCE(ln2.id, ln.id), COALESCE(ln2.name, ln.name)` ?????

Comment: @WebberDepor yeah that would work, though I'm not sure how useful that output would be.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one hop, then this is a simple `join`:

```
select t.id, (case when t.redirect_id is null then t.name else tr.name end) as name
from t left join
     t tr
     on t.redirect_id = tr.id;
```

If re-directs can have re-directs, you'll need more joins.  MySQL does not have good support for hierarchical/recursive queries.

Comment: forgot to add i need all redirected row not just redirected `name`.